# Jquery error: $(...).on is not a function

Tags: jquery

How do I fix error:

```
$(...).on is not a function
```

int he following line:

```
$(document.body).on('click', ".show_more", function(){
```

Comment: And make sure it's version 1.7 or later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that jQuery is included to your page. And check its version. It must be 1.7 or higher

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) Blue header after Description line, which says "version added: 1.7" There you can always find minimal version required for some function to work[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was sure I have jQuery version 1.8.3 but actually it was 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

If the jquery you are using is older than 1.7, then you have to use live.

```
$(document.body).live('click', ".show_more", function(){
```

But it is not a good practice to use it, since it will be outdated in the successive versions.